# In pandas, select all columns whose label contains a given string at a specified level

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write:

```
mydf[mydf.columns.get_level_values('level_2').str.contains('mystring')]
```

But that doesn't work.  What's the right syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
idx = mydf.columns.get_level_values('level_2').to_series().str.contains('mystring')
mydf.loc[:, idx.values]
```

or:

```
idx = mydf.columns.get_level_values('level_2').map(lambda t: 'mystring' in t)
mydf.loc[:, idx]
```

Comment: I wound up going with list interpolation: `mydf.loc[:, ['mystring' in label for label in mydf.columns.get_level_values('level_2')]]`